# Join table values If record exist MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel

I need join values from my `products` table only when record in `changes` table exist, on other ways get return only from `products` table, I trying use LEFT JOIN for it but doing something wrong. Also tables `changes` and `products` have same structure

```
    SELECT
    product.*, 
    parent.name, 
    parent.ignored, 
    child.name, 
    child.ignored, 
    changes.* 

    FROM
    products AS product 
    inner join parent_cat AS parent on product.parent_id = parent.ID 
    inner join child_cat AS child on product.category_id = child.ID 
    left join changes AS changes on changes.product_id = product.SKURcrd
    WHERE
       product.slug = 'some slug'
```

Returned data looks like:

```
{#389 ▼
  +"parent_id": 3
  +"category_id": 142
  +"product_id": null
  +"slug": "some slug"
  +"SKURcrd": "301832"
  +"product_name": null
  +"product_name_revert": "1911 AIR"
}
```

Tables Structure looks like (schematic):

```
-------------------------        ----------------------------
SKURcrd  |  product_name         product_id  |  product_name
-------------------------        ----------------------------
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of your logic would help.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with your left join there, but I suspect in simplifying your query you have perhaps removed the problem. Check your WHERE clause predicates for a reference to `changes` or post the full query please.

Comment: if some records exist in `changes` do you still want the records that don't exist in `changes`? In this case, you use left join and the records that don't exist will just be `null`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do that, either use INNER JOIN to changes or a where clause like where changes.  produc_id is not null... like below:

```
SELECT
product.*, 
parent.name, 
parent.ignored, 
child.name, 
child.ignored, 
changes.* 

FROM
products AS product 
inner join parent_cat AS parent on product.parent_id = parent.ID 
inner join child_cat AS child on product.category_id = child.ID 
left join changes AS changes on changes.product_id = product.SKURcrd
WHERE
   product.slug = 'some slug' and changes.product_id is not null
```

Comment: It's request return NULL when changes.product_id not found, I'm trying get data from only products table if product_id not found

Comment: Ok I guess I got confused when you said "I need join values from my products table only when record in changes table exist"   I tought you only wanted to see them if they did find the product_id.

Comment: Example products.product_name = 'Some name', changes.product_name = NULL, because changes table is empty, when I use left join I get product_name  = NULL, but need product_name = 'Some Name'.  Or products.product_name = "Some Name", but changes.product_name = "Some Name Changes",because changes table not empty and product_id = SKURcrd, in this case I need get product_name = "Some Name Changes". Make sense?